# Escalonamento de máquinas - Teoria dos Grafos

Tags: matemática, grafo

estou fazendo uma lista de exercícios de teoria dos grafos e empaquei em uma questão que tem o seguinte enunciado:

> São dadas máquinas 1, . . . , n e intervalos de tempo I1, . . . , In.
>   Para cada i, um operador deve cuidar da máquina i durante o intervalo
>   Ii. Se Ii ∩ Ij 6= ∅, um mesmo operador não pode cuidar de i e j. Qual
>   o número mínimo de operadores suficiente para operar as máquinas?
>   Apresente um exemplo com n ≥ 10. Para o exemplo, mostre o grafo que
>   modela o problema

Então, o que concluí até agora é que é um problema de matching, só que por não ser fornecido a interseção dos intervalos de tempo, na minha cabeça o número mínimo de funcionários seria 1 caso todos os intervalos de tempo fossem exatamente o mesmo, mas caso fossem "engatados" sequencialmente eu precisaria de 2 que se alternariam. Enfim, alguém consegue me dar uma luz? Acho que o que pensei até esse momento está completamente errado =/

Comment: Eu ainda não consegui modelar como grafo... modelei como conjuntos...

Comment: Entendi! Isso é um problema de coloração de grafos! Visualizei, o difícil é fazer os desenhos explicando...

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/257864/64969

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Vou dever as imagens, mas vou responder o melhor possível textualmente

Você está trabalhando com um problema de otimização. No caso específico, você quer minimizar a quantidade de operadores. Obviamente um operador só pode cuidar de uma máquina por vez neste problema.

Um problema clássico de otimização para o menor possível é o de [coloração de grafos](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colora%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_grafos). No caso, para usar esse esquema, precisamos mapear cada conceito de coloração de grafos no nosso problema atual.

- Vértices:
  Cada vértice é uma máquina. O vértice `i` representa a máquina `i`
- Arestas:
  Uma aresta `ij` significa que as máquinas `i` e `j` estão ligadas ao mesmo tempo. Ou então, mais formalmente, a interseção `I_i` com `I_j` é não vazia
- Cores:
  Cada cor é um operador. Como um operador só pode operar uma máquina por vez, dois vértices vizinhos não podem ter a mesma cor.

Uma propriedade muito interessante que advém dessas três definições acima é que todo clique é composto por máquinas que estão ativas exatamente ao mesmo tempo.

Um exemplo de grafo com 10 vértices poderia ser o mais simples de todos: sem interseção entre os intervalos de tempo, não há arestas e portanto a cor mínima é 1.

Não está dito na questão, mas esses intervalos deveriam ser contíguos. O que significa que se a minha máquina `k` é ligada das 10h até 12h, depois só é ligada novamente as 14h até 16h, isso gera algumas inconsistências. Mas de toda sorte poderia ser normalizado para intervalos contíguos separando `k` nas máquinas `k_1` e `k_2` para o primeiro e segundo intervalo de funcionamento respectivamente.

Caso se deseje um exemplo mais detalhado de grafo com pelo menos 10 vértices, é necessário atentar que esse problema não gera grafos aleatórios.

### Grafo inválido

Um exemplo de grafo inválido seria o seguinte grafo bipartido:

```
1 --- 2
 \   /
  \ /
   x
  / \
 /   \
3 --- 4
```

Pois não há intervalos contíguos que me permitam fazer essa construção de arestas.

Vamos tentar demonstrar?

A primeira coisa é saber que `I_1` e `I_3` não tem interseção, pois não tem aresta. Vou dizer que `I_1` ocorre antes de `I_3`. Posso afirmar isso sem perder generalidade.

Então vou por os seguintes valores:

```
I_1: [10, 12]
I_3: [14, 16]
```

`I_2` precisa ter interseção com `I_1` e `I_3` simultaneamente. Então, um valor bonito para `I_2` seria:

```
I_2: [11, 15]
```

Agora nos resta tentar criar `I_4`. Assim como `I_2`, pelo grafo `I_4` tem interseção com ambos `I_1` e `I_3`. Porém, `I_4` precisa não ter interseção com `I_2`. Qualquer valor que eu tentar por para `I_4` vai chocar com esses valores de `I_2`, no mínimo a interseção deles será `(12, 14)`. Então não é possível gerar `I_4` atendendo essas limitações de horário, portanto esse grafo não é aplicado ao problema de alocação de operadores a máquinas.

> Mas se eu estivesse trabalhando no grupo `Z mod 4`...

Vou interromper esse contra argumento logo! Estamos tentando modelar o mundo real, então essa matemática mais exótica aí não se aplica a máquinas ficando ligadas em intervalos de tempo. O tempo segue o princípio da boa ordenação, diferentemente de grupos circulares... portanto esse argumento é inválido para o problema modelado.

### Algoritmo de geração de grafos válidos

Não consegui ainda pensar em um algoritmo para validar se um grafo é válido ou não, mas eu sei como gerar um grafo válido.

Para esse algoritmo você precisará de uma folha em branco, de preferência pautada, e um lápis ou caneta. Defina a parte de cima da folha como "*o passado*", já a parte de baixo como "*o futuro*". Separe a folha em `n` colunas, sendo `n` o número de máquinas desejadas.

Então, para cada coluna, posicione o lápis em uma pauta e, sem tirá-lo do papel, risque até outra pauta mais abaixo. Esse risco feito na coluna `c` será o intervalo `I_c`. Por exemplo, para `n = 4`:

```
#
#   #
#   #      #
    #      #
           #
       #   #
       #   #
       #   #
           #
```

Note que temos aqui as seguintes interseções:

- máquina 1 com máquina 2, pois ambas estão nos tempos 2 e 3
- máquina 1 com máquina 2 com máquina 4, pois as três estão no tempo 3
- máquina 3 com máquina 4, pois o intervalo de tempo [6, 8] pertence a interseção `I_3` com `I_4`

Com essas informações das interseções em mãos, podemos desenhar nosso grafo. É esse grafo será válido para modelagem do nosso problema.

No caso acima, o grafo seria o seguinte:

```
1 --- 2
 \    |
  \   |
   \  |
    \ |
     \|
      4 --- 3
```

Que por sinal precisa de 3 cores.

### Algoritmo de geração  de grafos válidos, v2

Basicamente é a adaptação mais adequado a um modelo programático, menos didático:

Para `n` máquinas quaisquer, gere `n` pares de números `(A_i,B_i)` tal que `A_i < B_i`. Esses são os intervalos de tempo do funcionamento das máquinas. Se por acaso houver interseção não vazia entre `(A_i,B_i)` e `(A_j,B_j)`, então no grafo deve existir a aresta `ij`. Detectadas todas as interseções, você terá um grafo válido de `n` vértices para esse problema de alocação de operários por máquina

### Algoritmo para identificar grafos inválidos

Não tenho nenhum algoritmo em mente que faça essa detecção, por isso criei a seguinte questão: [Como identificar um grafo inválido para problema de alocação de operadores por máquina?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/257864/64969)

Comment: Para o grafo ser válido para o problema, ou seja, representar um conjunto de intervalos de forma que adjacências representam intervalos com sobreposição, então todos os ciclos com mais de 4 vértices precisam ter uma aresta que não faz parte do ciclo. Referências: https://www.ime.usp.br/~pf/algoritmos_em_grafos/aulas/interval-coloring.html e https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chordal_graph