# Algoritmo O(n log n) para identificar intervalos contíguos dada uma lista de intervalos

Tags: matemática, independente-de-linguagem, complexidade-de-algoritmo

Tenho o seguinte problema: Dada uma lista com `n` intervalos contínuos, retorne uma lista de `m` intervalos contínuos tal que:

- todo ponto da lista de entrada esteja contido em algum dos intervalos da segunda lista
- todo ponto da lista de saída seja de pelo menos um elemento da lista de entrada
- não haja interseção alguma entre os elementos da lista de saída

Exemplos de entrada e saída:

```
-- Entrada
1-3
2-6
7-10

-- Saída
1-6
7-10

-- Entrada
1-3
2-8
7-10

-- Saída
1-10

-- Entrada
1-3
4-7
8-10

-- Saída
1-3
4-7
8-10
```

A ordem da entrada e da saída são irrelevantes.

Esse problema é equivalente a descobrir quantos componentes conexos tem um grafo de intervalo, apresentado apenas os vértices/intervalos desse grafo, e qual o intervalo representado por cada componente conexo.

A estratégia que eu consegui pensar segue uma lógica quadrática. Segue um pseudo-código em Java:

```java
List<Intervalo> entrada = ...;
ArrayList<Intervalo> saída = new ArrayList<>();

processaEntrada: for (Intervalo intervaloEntrada: entrada) {
  Integer firstNullPosition = null;
  Intervalo intervaloInserido = intervaloEntrada.copia();
  ArrayList<Integer> índicesInterseção = new ArrayList<>();
  for (int i = 0; i < saída.length(); i++) {
    Intervalo intervaloJulgamento = saída.get(i);
    if (intervaloJulgamento == null) {
      if (firstNullPosition == null) {
        firstNullPosition = i;
      }
      continue;
    }
    // como a lista  saida só contém elementos sem interseção entre si,
    // é impossível que seja possível que essa comparação e a de alguma 
    // interseção com outro elemento de saida aconteçam
    if (intervaloJulgamento.contemIntervalo(intervaloInserido) {
      continue processaEntrada;
    }
    if (háInterseção(intervaloJulgamento, intervaloInserido)) {
      índicesInterseção.add(i);
    }
  }
  // se índicesInterseção for não vazio, então houve alguma interseção
  // caso contrário não houve interseção e, portanto, o intervaloInserido está
  // pronto para ser adicionado na lista
  if (índicesInterseção.isEmpty()) {
    if (firstNullPosition != null) {
      saída.set(firstNullPosition, intervaloInserido);
    } else {
      saída.add(intervaloInserido);
    }
  } else {
    Intervalo intervaloInterseções = intervaloInserido;
    int idxInserção = índicesInterseção.get(0);
    for (Integer i: índicesInterseção) {
      Intervalo interseptado = saída.get(i);
      saída.set(i, null);
      intervaloInterseções.começo = min(intervaloInterseções.começo, interseptado.começo);
      intervaloInterseções.fim = max(intervaloInterseções.fim, interseptado.fim);
    }
    saída.set(idxInserção, intervaloInterseções);
  }
}

return saída.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Olha Jeff, eu espero que você mesmo responda isso...

Comment: @VictorStafusa, o exemplo foi em Java, mas o problema é independente de linguagem (apesar de eu precisar resolver isso imperativamente, pontos extras para quem fizer em Lisp de modo funcional provando a complexidade). Obrigado por reparar nisso

Comment: @LINQ, na verdade eu já estou bolando uma espécie de árvore binária de busca para fazer essa função de merge mesmo =P Na verdade, como eu não domino balancear árvores, ainda vai ser uma espécie de "caso médio", mas daí seria trocar as operações de "merge" de nodos para alguma remoção com rotação da AVL ou da rubro-negra

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Dei a resposta em Java. Traduzir isso pra Lisp fica pra você (embora provavelmente vai ficar bem mais simples que no Java).

Comment: Ah, @JeffersonQuesado Acabei de editar a minha resposta porque tinha um caso especial que dava errado (quando os intervalos apenas se encostavam, como por exemplo [1, 3] e [3, 10]). Editei ela para corrigir isso.

Comment: Sim, percebi isso quando entendi o `Evento`, mas a solução era trivial para não incomodar você com isso (no máximo fazer uma edição)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O código em Java que montei é o seguinte:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * @author Victor Williams Stafusa da Silva
 */
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Intervalo.reduzir(new Intervalo(1, 3), new Intervalo(2, 6), new Intervalo(7, 10)));
        System.out.println(Intervalo.reduzir(new Intervalo(1, 3), new Intervalo(2, 8), new Intervalo(7, 10)));
        System.out.println(Intervalo.reduzir(new Intervalo(1, 3), new Intervalo(4, 7), new Intervalo(8, 10)));
        System.out.println(Intervalo.reduzir(new Intervalo(1, 3), new Intervalo(3, 10)));
    }
}

final class Intervalo {
    private final double a;
    private final double b;

    public Intervalo(double a, double b) {
        if (b < a) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public double getA() {
       return a;
    }

    public double getB() {
       return b;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[" + a + "<->" + b + "]";
    }

    public Evento getEventoA() {
        return new Evento(true, a);
    }

    public Evento getEventoB() {
        return new Evento(false, b);
    }

    @SafeVarargs
    public static List<Intervalo> reduzir(Intervalo... lista) {
        return reduzir(List.of(lista));
    }

    public static List<Intervalo> reduzir(List<Intervalo> lista) {
        List<Evento> eventos = new ArrayList<>(lista.size() * 2);
        for (Intervalo i : lista) {
            eventos.add(i.getEventoA());
            eventos.add(i.getEventoB());
        }
        Collections.sort(eventos);
        List<Intervalo> saida = new ArrayList<>(lista.size());
        int contagem = 0;
        double inicio = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
        for (Evento e : eventos) {
            if (e.isInicioIntervalo()) {
                if (contagem == 0) inicio = e.getPonto();
                contagem++;
            } else {
                contagem--;
                if (contagem == 0) saida.add(new Intervalo(inicio, e.getPonto()));
            }
        }
        return saida;
    }
}

final class Evento implements Comparable<Evento> {
    private final boolean inicioIntervalo;
    private final double ponto;

    public Evento(boolean inicioIntervalo, double ponto) {
        this.inicioIntervalo = inicioIntervalo;
        this.ponto = ponto;
    }

    public boolean isInicioIntervalo() {
        return inicioIntervalo;
    }

    public double getPonto() {
        return ponto;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Evento outro) {
        return this.ponto < outro.ponto ? -1
                : this.ponto > outro.ponto ? 1
                : this.inicioIntervalo == outro.inicioIntervalo ? 0
                : this.inicioIntervalo ? -1
                : 1;
    }
}
```

Vejamos qual é a complexidade do método estático `reduzir`:

```java
        List<Evento> eventos = new ArrayList<>(lista.size() * 2);
```

Esse é **O(n)**. Observe que dei um tamanho exato para a lista (**2n**) suficiente para que ela não precise ser redimensionada nunca. O método `size()` é **O(1)**.

```java
        for (Intervalo i : lista) {
            eventos.add(i.getEventoA());
            eventos.add(i.getEventoB());
        }
```

Os getters são **O(1)**. O método `add` é **O(1)** se a lista não precisar ser redimensionada (e ela nunca precisará). O número de `Evento`s criados na lista é **2n**.

```java
        Collections.sort(eventos);
```

Ordenação é **O(tn log n)**, onde **t** é a complexidade do método `compareTo` da classe `Evento`. Como esse método tem complexidade **O(1)**, então isso se reduz a **O(n log n)**. Esse é o ponto que faz o algoritmo ter tal complexidade.

```java
        List<Intervalo> saida = new ArrayList<>(lista.size());
```

Novamente é **O(n)** e nunca precisará ser redimensionada, pois o pior caso é justamente quando nenhum dos intervalos se sobrepõe aos demais.

```java
        int contagem = 0;
        double inicio = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
```

Isso daí é **O(1)**.

```java
        for (Evento e : eventos) {
            if (e.isInicioIntervalo()) {
                if (contagem == 0) inicio = e.getPonto();
                contagem++;
            } else {
                contagem--;
                if (contagem == 0) saida.add(new Intervalo(inicio, e.getPonto()));
            }
        }
```

Considerando que o número de eventos é **2n**, então esse `for` também é **O(n)**.

Os métodos `isInicioIntervalo`, `getPonto`, `add` (considerando que `saida` nunca precisará ser redimensionada) e o construtor de `Intervalo` também são todos **O(1)**.

```java
        return saida;
```

Isso é **O(1)**.

Basicamente o algoritmo se reduz a desmanchar os intervalos e marcá-los como uma sequência ordenada de pontos, onde cada ponto correspondente ao início de um intervalo soma 1 em `contagem` e cada ponto equivalente ao fim subtrai 1 de `contagem`.

Quando `contagem` sai do zero, é porque estamos em algum intervalo que abriu.

Enquanto `contagem` for maior que zero, há intervalos abertos colidindo entre si. E o número de `contagem` diz exatamente quantos.

Quando `contagem` é reduzido para zero, significa que todos os intervalos que estavam abertos fecharam e podemos então adicionar um grande intervalo correspondendo a tudo isso, desde o ponto onde essa variável saiu do zero até o ponto em que voltou a ele.

A complexidade do algoritmo é dominada pela ordenação, que é a operação de maior complexidade (**O(n log n)**).

Uma vez que os elementos na lista `eventos` estão devidamente ordenados, isso garante que os elementos de `saida` também estarão corretos e devidamente ordenados.

Vale também dar uma atenção ao método `compareTo`:

```java
    public int compareTo(Evento outro) {
        return this.ponto < outro.ponto ? -1
                : this.ponto > outro.ponto ? 1
                : this.inicioIntervalo == outro.inicioIntervalo ? 0
                : this.inicioIntervalo ? -1
                : 1;
    }
```

Ele é assim para garantir que os `Evento`s com menores números sempre antecederão os de maior número. E em caso de empate, que um evento de abertura de intervalo sempre tenha precedência sobre um de fechamento. Isso serve para garantir que intervalos que apenas estejam encostando (por exemplo, [1-3] e [3-10]) sejam considerados como uma colisão.

Caso seja desejado que eventos que estão apenas encostando não sejam considerados como uma colisão, basta trocar o `? -1 : 1;` do final por `? 1 : -1;`.

Considerando esses intervalos de entrada:

```java
System.out.println(Intervalo.reduzir(new Intervalo(1, 3), new Intervalo(2, 6), new Intervalo(7, 10)));
System.out.println(Intervalo.reduzir(new Intervalo(1, 3), new Intervalo(2, 8), new Intervalo(7, 10)));
System.out.println(Intervalo.reduzir(new Intervalo(1, 3), new Intervalo(4, 7), new Intervalo(8, 10)));
System.out.println(Intervalo.reduzir(new Intervalo(1, 3), new Intervalo(3, 10)));
```

Eis a saída produzida:

```
[[1.0<->6.0], [7.0<->10.0]]
[[1.0<->10.0]]
[[1.0<->3.0], [4.0<->7.0], [8.0<->10.0]]
[[1.0<->10.0]]
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no IDEONE**](https://ideone.com/GbmcB5).

Comment: Não tinha percebido que poderia definir os `Evento`s como entrada/saída e daí seria só ordenar. Estava lutando montando uma árvore e fazendo "reduções" nela.